# DCOM CoCreateInstanceEx 0x80040155

Tags: c++, dcom

DCOM client is situated under WIN server 2012, DCOM server is located under WIN XP. When I call CoCreateInstanceEx it returns `0x80040155` "Interface not registered".

Actions that were already performed:

- Register COM classes on the serverside via `MyApp.exe /regserver`
- Checked the registry (on server side) if the appropriate APPIDs and interface CLSIDs are there.
- Configured DCOM on the server side via `DCOMCNFG`(based on this [link](https://www.softwaretoolbox.com/dcom/html/dcom_for_windows_vista-xp-_-_server_2003.html))
- Also enabled DCOM on the client side via `DCOMCNFG`
- Enabled DCOM event logging via `ActivationFailureLoggingLevel` and `CallFailureLoggingLevel` registry keys -> no errors found in event log.

Though I've performed above steps I still the 0x80040155  error code from CoCreateInstanceEx.

Is there a way to enable additional DCOM tracing on the server side, to get more information why 0x80040155 is returned?

Any additional hints to get rid of this problem?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that you also have to register COM server interface on your client machine, otherwise you might get above described error code.